# Consultas anidadas en Oracle (select dentro de otro select)

Tags: oracle

Tengo una consulta que hice en otros manejadores (SQLite, MySQL y PostgreSQL), la cual me funcionó bajo la misma estructura en todos ellos, pero cuando voy a Oracle me da un error que dice:

```
"ORA-00937: not a single-group group function"
```

La consulta es esta que les muestro. Al parecer, el problema está en las subconsultas de "VotantesAbstencion" y "PorcentajeAbstencion", por cuanto estoy anidando un select dentro de otro. Estoy buscando algunas ayudas, pero no encuentro algo que me especifique claramente cómo debo hacer la adaptación para Oracle.

```
  SELECT sum(actovoto.participo) AS votantesparticipacion,
    ((sum(actovoto.participo) * 100) / count(actovoto.participo)) AS porcentajeparticipacion,
    ( SELECT count(actovoto_1.participo) AS count
           FROM actovoto actovoto_1
          WHERE (actovoto_1.participo = 0)) AS votantesabstencion,
    ( SELECT (( SELECT (count(actovoto_2.participo) * 100)
                   FROM actovoto actovoto_2
                  WHERE (actovoto_2.participo = 0)) / count(actovoto_1.participo))
           FROM actovoto actovoto_1) AS porcentajeabstencion
   FROM actovoto
```

Muchas gracias de antemano a quienes puedan orientarme sobre cuál modificación debo hacer.

Comment: todos esos manejadores de db te dejan hacer consultas que no son sql ansi.. te falta un group by... oracle no sabe como hacer ese su, sin eso...

Comment: En dónde colocaría ese otro group by, @gbianchi?

Comment: si no necesitas agrupar, y solo queres un sum de toda una tabla...entonces seria otro sub select... si no, deberias agrupar por algun campo...

Comment: Básicamente lo que necesito es mostrar en una sola consulta el resultado de cuatro renglones: la suma de la participación total de votantes, el porcentaje de participación, la cantidad de abstención y el porcentaje de abstención. Es en estos dos últimos puntos donde tengo el problema, porque debo hacer las subconsultas que ves en el código que coloqué, @gbianchi. Realmente tengo la duda porque no manejo Oracle. Es primera vez que uso eso para una tarea.

Comment: 1)Debe editar la pregunta y pegar la consulta de manera que se vea organizada o formateada y 2) Puede suministrar un ejemplo de los datos y el resultado esperado?